# CPU usage is low using simulation software PTV Vissim in i5 3470 or ryzen 5 on all cores

Tags: simulation, cpu-usage, traffic-simulation

I don't know how to put this,but shouldn't cpu usage be as high as possible when running mathematical simulations ?
I am simulating traffic conditions using ptv vissim, but the cpu usage for a multi core i5 3470 is only about 50%. What stops the CPU from running faster or I am misinterpreting the usage value ? Please provide your insights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vissim as a traffic simulator doesn't involve CPU-intensive mathematical operations (such as a prime number searching, encryption/decryption, or large-dimension matrix operations).

It is quite normal that you see 50% CPU load when running Vissim simulation.